# Loading Dbpedia data and ontologies into virtuoso locally

Tags: python, rdf, sparql, dbpedia, virtuoso

I am trying to set up dbpedia sparql endpoint locally with the help of virtuoso triple store.
I followed two links.

1. [Loading data with the help of folders](http://dbpv.wordpress.com/2013/06/11/setting-up-a-dbpedia-mirror/)
2. [Loading data with the help of symbolic links](http://joernhees.de/blog/2014/04/23/setting-up-a-local-dbpedia-3-9-mirror-with-virtuoso-7/)

from these links. I followed the configurations according to the second link and I tried to load the data only from "en" folder and dbpedia-owl.owl file into "en" folder itself. I tried to load this en folder with the following command onto isql

```
ld_dir_all('/media/D8849AB0849A911C/datasets/en','*','http://dbpedia.org');
```

I did the further processing for committing this data. Then checked the data onto the local endpoint "localhost:8890/sparql". But the prefix "dbpedia-owl" seems to be missing. I also   checked into the list of "namespace prefixes". but "dbpedia-owl" seems to be missing. What did i do wrong while loading the data? Also I tried to add dbpedia-owl.gz file too. But the "dbpedia-owl" still doesnt seems to work on the endpoint.

when i tried to query this

```
select ?type {
   ?type a owl:Class .
} LIMIT 5
```

I got the result as

```
type
http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing
http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Nothing
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Abbey
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Abbey
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/AcademicJournal
```

So this result shows the data from ontology file. But the "dbpedia-owl" is not getting linked to this ontology file. Help is appreciated.

Comment: "But the property "dbpedia-owl" seems to be missing."  `dbpedia-owl` isn't a property, it's a predefined prefix on the public SPARQL endpoint's web interface for `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/`, but that's all…  I haven't configured Virtuoso, so I don't know how predefined prefixes are set up, but that's where you'd want to handle this;  it's not an aspect of the data.

Comment: yup..but when i configured virtuoso locally. the "dbpedia-owl" prefix is not configured for "http://dbpedia.org/ontology/". I am not getting why its happening.

Comment: Are any predefined namespaces loaded?  Any that are specific to DBpedia, or just generally common ones?  I guess what I'm wondering is whether there's some reason to expect the predefined prefix to be defined after loading the data?

Comment: all other prefixes seems to be loaded. also i tried some queries too which is not dependent on this prefix. they are working too.

Comment: Any idea why the prefixes that were created *were* created? If you can answer that, you might be able to figure out why dbpedia-owl *wasn't*.

Comment: So you mean to say if you remove this condition `{ { ?dbpedia_link rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Film .} UNION { ?dbpedia_link rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Person .} }` does it work...

Comment: Umm, that query (that was in a since deleted comment) has `PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Ontology>`  That's not the right prefix.  It needs to be `prefix dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>`.

Comment: sorry. This is the query I had tried
`PREFIX bif: <bif:>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?dbpedia_link str(?name) as ?label WHERE {
?dbpedia_link rdfs:label ?label1 . 
?dbpedia_link foaf:name ?name .

} LIMIT 100`

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor the prefix mentioned here http://dbpedia.org/sparql?nsdecl according to that `dbpedia-owl` seems to be correct

Comment: @Wazzzy Yes, that shows the correct prefix URI.  A previous version of Gunjan's comment had an incorrect prefix.  But I'm not clear where any of these prefixes are coming from.  The concept of an endpoint having default prefixes is just an implementation detail.  The *data* that's being queried over doesn't have anything to with with whether the endpoint has or doesn't have some predefined namespace.  Whether you have `dbpedia-owl: <...>` or not, the underlying *data* will still be using properties `<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/...>`.

Comment: @Gunjan when you go on this link http://192.168.1.236:8890/sparql?nsdecl do you get `dbpedia-owl` listed over there

Comment: @Wazzzy: nope I dont get that here. By default it did not get loaded here when i imported data into virtuoso.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor : you are right about the namespaces. Its not the problem related to namespaces. I loaded the namespaces into namespace prefixes list. Still I am getting the same problem. It seems that triple I am trying to find is not present in the data.

Comment: @gunjan, in your question, you showed a query and some results that it returned, but didn't say what it's *not* returning. *What* "triple you are trying to find is not present in the data"?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor : thankz for your help. It seems that some of the data I had missed out while loading the data onto virtuoso server. So we were getting blank results for the queries. Its working now :)

Comment: Too much conversation!  Not enough answer!  @Gunjan -- Please edit the relevant aspects of the comment thread into an answer, post it, and accept it...

For future reference, questions specifically regarding [OpenLink Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com) are generally best raised on [the public OpenLink Discussion Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support), [the Virtuoso Users mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=virtuoso-users), or through [a confidential Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp).

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late answer, but I stumbled across this question...

As far as I know, you loaded the ontology into virtuoso (so the classes and properties definitions are available in the DB), but this is different from defining a prefix and associating it with an URL.

If you want to do the later programmatically, just use :

```
DB.DBA.XML_SET_NS_DECL ('dbpedia-owl', 'http://dbpedia.org/ontology/', 2);
```

This just tell to virtuoso that, locally, the dbpedia-owl prefix will be used to denote the dbpedia ontology URL. There is now such thing as an universal prefix, hence you may also want to use any other prefix like `dbpo` or whatever you see fit on your local virtuoso server.